# Catching deleted letter in CKEDITOR 4.0

Tags: ckeditor, range, nodes, onkeydown

I need to catch the keydown event for the delete/backspace button. 
The problem is when the caret is on the beginning or end of a Tag/Block. 
In this momement i need to catch the letter of the previous/next block/tag.

But to start i can't find out how to move my range to the last letter of the previous block?
I already tried to move it by using:

```
var element = range.getPreviousNode(); // This returns a Text-Node
range.moveToElementEditablePosition(element,true); // This gives a error
```

The Error sais: TypeError: h is null ckeditor.js(line 364)
But i think this is because you can't move the focus to a text node?

The question is, how is it possible to catch the letter that is about to delete? Without interupting the CKEDITOR workflow. This so that i don't have to build the logic of switching between blocks/tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store `editor.edtaible().getText()` on each `key` event and compare it with the previous value by using some diff algorithm. This one feels good: https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/

The reason is that in some cases, backspace/delete will delete more than one letter, e.g. when caret is after some block element (entire block will be gone) or there's a lot of text selected. Besides, a caret positioning system in CKEditor is unpredictable (browsers are buggy and unpredictable), and your way can lead you into troubles.

Comment: I thought of this solution, but it's to heavy because the text files that i have to compare can be very big.. and to compare it at a keydown event can stop my application. Or scare away my clients. I am wiling tot take the risk of understanding and using the unpredictable positioning system in CKEditor. i would love to find out where the developers of CKEditor handle this delete event

Comment: But this indeed is a solution. I will try it and if it doesn't show any big delays, i will use it.

Comment: "this delete event" - there's no delete event. Deleting stuff is handled natively by the browser and you cannot attach listeners to it. This is why this is so hard.